# How do I combine results of two querys , NOT into one column, but adding them together so they all appear as a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been looking at videos, reading my textbook, and looking at examples, but nothing seems to work. I'm almost ready to give up, but I really want to figure this out because it seems simple enough. The goal is to basically take two results and add them together so all of them appear as one result into multiple columns.

This is my SQL so far consisting of the two SELECT statement's results I wish to combine,

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[School].SchoolName, 
    [dbo].[Professor].LastName, 
    [dbo].[Professor].FirstName

  FROM [dbo].[SchoolDean], [dbo].[School],[dbo].[DepartmentChair], [dbo].[Department], [dbo].[Professor]
   WHERE ([dbo].[SchoolDean].ProfessorID = [dbo].[Professor].[ProfessorID] AND
 [dbo].[School].SchoolID = [dbo].[SchoolDean].SchoolID)

SELECT DISTINCT 
[dbo].[Department].DepartmentName, 
    [dbo].[Professor].LastName, 
    [dbo].[Professor].FirstName
  FROM [dbo].[DepartmentChair], [dbo].[Department], [dbo].[Professor], [dbo].[SchoolDean], [dbo].[School]
WHERE [dbo].[DepartmentChair].ProfessorID = [dbo].[Professor].[ProfessorID] 
AND
  [dbo].[Department].DepartmentID = [dbo].[DepartmentChair].DepartmentID
```

The output is as follows for the First SELECT Statement:

```
SchoolName  LastName    FirstName
Education   |Brown      |Harold
Engineering |Yang       |Kim
Fine Arts   |Winsor     |Deborah
Management  |Smith      |Nancy
Mathematics |MacNamara  |Christine
Science     |Santiago   |Jose
```

This is my result for the Second SELECT Statement:

```
DepartmentName      LastName    FirstName
Aerospace          |Hastings    |Timothy
Applied Mathematics|McDonald    |Susan
Biology            |Noble       |Charles
Chemistry          |Young       |Margaret
Civil Engineering  |Hohl        |Patrick
Computer Science   |MacNamara   |Christine
Dance              |Winsor      |Stephen
Economics          |Anthony     |Todd
Elementary Education|Walker     |Joanne
Marketing          |Smith       |Nancy
MSIS               |Jones       |Samuel
Music              |Winsor      |Deborah
Physics            |Santiago    |Jose
Special Education  |Walker      |Joanne
```

The Desired result would look something like this, but having the SchoolName that is associated with the professor. Column and it's values added onto it, I don't mind null values:

```
DepartmentName      LastName    FirstName   SchoolName   LastName   FirstName
Aerospace          |Hastings    |Timothy
Applied Mathematics|McDonald    |Susan
Biology            |Noble       |Charles
Chemistry          |Young       |Margaret
Civil Engineering  |Hohl        |Patrick
Computer Science   |MacNamara   |Christine
Dance              |Winsor      |Stephen
Economics          |Anthony     |Todd
Elementary Education|Walker     |Joanne
Marketing          |Smith       |Nancy
MSIS               |Jones       |Samuel
Music              |Winsor      |Deborah
Physics            |Santiago    |Jose
Special Education  |Walker      |Joanne
```

Any help, recommendations or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you! - I think that what you are looking for is the `JOIN` statement. You could join the 2 queries on the Name

Comment: With the union operator. In case you are using mssql check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Can you provide the database structure of the other databases you are using? I strongly advice to never use joins by doing `select * from Table1, Table2, Table3` but to use proper fully written `JOIN` statements.

Comment: (1) *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  Learn SQL correctly!  (2) The use of `SELECT DISTINCT` is highly suspect. Your `JOIN` conditions are probably broken if it is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

use UNION ALL:

```
Select Schoolname as DepartmentName ...
UNION ALL
Select DepartmentName ...
```